# Assigning the output of a BQ query to variable (STANDARD SQL VIEW)

Tags: google-bigquery

We have several views created in a dataset which are a Standard SQL view.

I want to pass the output of the query to the variable in the shell script,
But I am facing the below error:

```
-bash: mydataset.view_name: command not found
```

Here is my command :

```
query1="bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --quiet --format=csv 'SELECT COUNT(1) as Count FROM `mydataset.view_name`' | awk '{if(NR>1)print}'"

eval result=\$\($query1\)

echo "$result"
```

And I can not use Legacy SQL as it gives the following error:

> Cannot reference a standard SQL view in a legacy SQL
>   query.

The command above is working fine for all of my tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backticks since you are using Bash:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --quiet --format=csv 'SELECT COUNT(1) as Count FROM \`mydataset.view_name\`'
```